# CakePHP 3: Export to excel files

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP, I'm using version 3.0, and have asked before how to export to Excel using **PHPExcel**. I have downloaded and installed it in the vendor folder and created the different files as follows:

**controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Tests Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\TestsTable $Tests
 */
class TestsController extends AppController
{
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Csv','PHPExcel'); 

    public function exportoexcel()
    {
        $this->set('data',$this->Tests->find('all'));
        $this->response->download("export.xls");
    }
}
```

**src/template/.ctp**

```
<?php
$this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet()
    ->setDefaultFont('Calibri', 12);

// define table cells
$table = array(
    array('label' => __('User'), 'filter' => true),
    array('label' => __('Type'), 'filter' => true),
    array('label' => __('Date')),
    array('label' => __('Description'), 'width' => 50, 'wrap' => true),
    array('label' => __('Modified'))
);

// add heading with different font and bold text
$this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));

// add data
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(

    ));
}

// close table and output
$this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter()
    ->output();
?>
```

In the **src/view/helper** folder I have created the **phpexcel.php** and **phpexcelhelper** file .

Then when I run the application I always get this error:

> require(C:\wamp\www\qualite2\qualite\src\View\Helper\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/View\Helper\PHPExcel.php, line 32]

**Code Context**

```
if (!defined('PHPEXCEL_ROOT')) {
    define('PHPEXCEL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) );
    require(PHPEXCEL_ROOT . '\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php');
```

Comment: Please mind your formatting (**http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting**) - thanks!

Comment: Are you using plugin for CakePHP 3 or creating your own?
https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#templating

Comment: i installed phpOffice/ composer using composer as recomended from this website https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel  i load the plugin in the config/bootstrap file Plugin::load('PhpExcel');

Comment: then i modifie the cakephp-plugins by adding 'PhpExcel' => $baseDir . '/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/' line and i add the phpExcelhelper class but ones i load the application i get always the same probleme  Class 'App\View\Helper\PHPExcel' not found 
File C:\wamp\www\qualite2\qualite\src\View\Helper\PHPExcelHelper.php 
Line: 44  which the code where the error is produced is as follows    public function createWorksheet() {
        // load vendor classes
        App::classname('Vendor', 'PhpExcel');
        $this->_xls = new PHPExcel();
        $this->_row = 1;
        return $this;
    }

Comment: In case your Excel helper is sort of a plugin: Did you also [load it in the bootstrap file](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#loading-a-plugin)?

Comment: thanks for youre help yes i did i found a solution instead of loading by single plugin i used loadallplugin but i encounter another probleme that after generating the xls file how can i redirect to the index page public function exportoexcel()
    {      
  //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']) 
  
    } because after calling this action instead of generating the page and then redirect to the index it redirects directly to index skipping the creation of file

Comment: @wasimH according to your original post. I want to ask what code was contained in files **phpexcel.php** and **phpexcelhelper file** in **src/view/helper folder**.  OR if it is possible, can u post some simple tutorial how to properly set it up working. Thnx.